# bijective, one-to-one, and number of elements

Tags: number-theory, cardinals

How does one reconcile the following (seemingly) contradiction in 
using "number of elements" argument?

In the "range" [0,1] in R there are more points than in N, to be shown as
"take the inverse of every element of N and you end up with holes in [0,1]"
This seems a valid argument.

Similarly it seems that [0,2] has twice the number of points as [0,1]
Maybe it is invalid to claim this, but then why would the above be valid?

Is it fair to say that $f(x)= y = 2x$ 
with domain [0,1] and range [0,2] is bijective?
no holes on the x-axis and no holes on the y-axis,
mapped one-to-one but y-range still looks like to have twice the (infinite) number of elements.
Does cardinality come to the rescue here, but then what about the
one-to-one part of used for explaining bijectiveness?

I find this confusing, but I am sure many around here can clear this up, for this simple example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

- While it is true that the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ is smaller than that of $[0,1]$ your argument is *not a proof* for.  The former set is (infinite) countable while the latter has the cardinality of the continuum which is greater. This can be shown in a not too complicated way, yet there is some work to be done, going quite a bit beyond your argument.
- The map $x \mapsto 2x$ is indeed a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,2]$. The two sets have the same cardinality, the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take yor word for it that the argument is not a proof, allthough I do not understand that (yet).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take your word for it that the argument is not a proof, allthough I do not understand that (yet).<BR> To me it seems that diag. Cantor shows that numbers are missing, like above argument. <BR> I found this [link](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/math-proof/cardinality/cardinality.html) of which I can gain some more knowledge.

Comment: Yes Cantor's diagonalisation allows a proof. To see why your argument cannot be valid note that if you were to consider the rational numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ than also not all of them are inverses of natural numbers, while there cardinality is in fact the same as that of the natural numbers.